# Bootstrap Theme vs Template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the difference between Bootstrap Template and Bootstrap Theme? I am quite confused. Does a Theme use a Template? Can I use different templates with a Theme?

Answer (score 11):

Typically:

A theme consists of customized CSS.

A template consists of one or more predesigned HTML pages, which very often (but not necessarily) also make use of a theme.

Answer (score 1):

A "theme" refers to the style layer or "skin". A "theme" encompasses colors, fonts and style.

A "template" refers to a page layout, and its' HTML structure.